# Convert a one-band GTIFF to PNG with adjusted color ramp using GDAL

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, gdal-translate, png, color-ramp

I have a one-band fCover GTiff with values ranging between 0 to 0.4 and I would like to convert it to a png using a color ramp adapted to this tiff.
I already have a png from this tif but the color ramp is adapted to values ranging from 0 to 1. So, in my case, the png is not enough contrasted and colors not very adapted. Here is the png I have:

[image]

I tried `gdal_translate`

```
gdal_translate.exe -of jpeg -expand rgb -a_nodata 255 -co worldfile=yes tif_filepath output_jpg_filepath
```

And I get this error in return:

```
ERROR 1: Error : band 1 has no color table
```

Do you have any clue of what is happening ? Maybe `gdal_translate` is not the best way to do that? Is it generally possible?